# AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'get' - Flask-Login User class with PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo, flask-login

I have created a user class for Flask-Login as shown below:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    users = mongo.db.users
    u = users.find_one({"_id": user_id})
    return User(u)

class User(UserMixin):

    def __init__(self, user_json):
        self.user_json = user_json

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def is_active(self):
        return True

    def get_id(self):
        object_id = self.user_json.get('_id')
        return str(object_id)

    def get_reset_token(self, expires_sec=3600):
        s = Serializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'], expires_sec)
        id = str(self.user_json.get('_id'))
        return s.dumps({'user_id': id}).decode('utf-8')


    @staticmethod
    def verify_reset_token(token):
        s = Serializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        try:
            user_id = s.loads(token)['user_id']
        except:
            return None
        return load_user(user_id)
```

and I have a user account route where the user should be able to edit and delete their account. However, to get the user and update/delete from the database I need to use the pymongo code:

```
users = mongo.db.users
user = users.find_one({'_id': user_id})
```

or

```
user = users.find_one({'email': user_email})
```

to get the appropriate user from the database, and to do this I need to get the ID from the current user.
When I try current_user.get_id() I get the following error:

```
builtins.AttributeError
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/Users/leawhitelaw/enu_group_project/src/app_f/routes.py", line 135, in account
current_user.get_id()
File "/Users/leawhitelaw/enu_group_project/src/app_f/db_classes.py", line 29, in get_id
object_id = self.user_json.get('_id')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

and if I try cast User around the current_user (noting that current_user is a flask-login attribute) then I get the error:

```
builtins.AttributeError
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'get'

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/Users/leawhitelaw/enu_group_project/src/app_f/routes.py", line 126, in account
user.get_id()
File "/Users/leawhitelaw/enu_group_project/src/app_f/db_classes.py", line 29, in get_id
object_id = self.user_json.get('_id')
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'get'
```

It is also confusing that is that in the get_reset_token function, getting the _id works because that function is working perfectly well when I use it. I have also tried:

```
current_user._id 
current_user['_id'] 
current_user.email
current_user['email']
```

in which I get that NoneType is not subscriptable or User type is not subscriptable.

I understand that the User object is not the same as the users in my database, but I need to get some information from the current_user to be able to connect it to the appropriate user in the DB.

Answer (score 1):

The User class here has no `get()` method by default and also doesn't implement `__getitem__()` method necessary to support `user["email"]` or similar access patterns, which is the root cause of your errors.

The call to `get_reset_token()` works because it makes a call to `self.user_json.get('_id'))` where `user_json` is the wrapped dictionary which does support get and subscriptable access.

Possible solutions:

### 1. Proxy get and __getitem__ to the wrapped dictionary

This is a partial solution and there are several other magic methods to implement to make User act more like a dictionary but this is a starting point.

```
class User(UserMixin):
  ...
  def get(self, key):
    return self.user_json.get(key)

  def __getitem__(self, key):
    return self.user_json[key]

  def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    return self.user_json[key] = value

  def __delitem__(self, key):
    del self.user_json[key]
  ...
```

### 2. Create properties for specific access patterns

Properties are more pythonic than getter methods like `get_email()`.

```
class User(UserMixin):
  ...
  @property
  def email(self):
    return self.user_json["email"]

  @email.setter
  def email(self, value):
    self.user_json["email"] = value
  ...
```

Comment: I am still getting the error" 'User' Object is not subscriptable" from the line:
self.user_json['email']

Comment: This would suggest that the object you are passing into the User constructor is another User object rather than a dict of user data.  From your initial code sample self.user_json should be a dict and not a User object.  Without seeing the full code it is hard to say what the issue is.